# Sort array of custom string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

using array sort BinRange is not sorted expected and also. Using  Loadash methods also not able to get the result

Loadash:

```
loadash.orderBy(resData, AgeBin, 'asc');
loadash.sortBy(resData, [function(o) { return o.AgeBin; }]);
```

Input:

```
[
    {
        'BinRange': '100-110',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '110-120',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '120-130',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '70-80',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '80-90',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '90-100',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '>150',
    },
];
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        'BinRange': '70-80',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '80-90',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '90-100',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '100-110',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '110-120',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '120-130',
    },
    {
        'BinRange': '>150',
    },
];
```

Please suggest a way to do it

Comment: Seems like your input uses `BinRange` while your code sorts by `AgeBin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getProperStartRange(range) {
  if (range["BinRange"][0] === ">") {
    return Number.parseInt(range["BinRange"].slice(1)) + 1;
  } else if (range["BinRange"][0] === "<") {
    return Number.parseInt(range["BinRange"].slice(1)) - 1;
  } else {
    return Number.parseInt(range["BinRange"].split("-")[0]);
  }
}

function sortBinRange(array) {
  array.sort((a, b) => {
    const rangeA = getProperStartRange(a);
    const rangeB = getProperStartRange(b);
    return rangeA - rangeB;
  });
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort based on the number at the end of the `BinRange` string. Use `/\d+$/` to get that number

```js
const input = [{BinRange:"100-110"},{BinRange:"110-120"},{BinRange:"120-130"},{BinRange:"70-80"},{BinRange:"80-90"},{BinRange:"90-100"},{BinRange:">150"}];

input.sort((a,b) => a.BinRange.match(/\d+$/g)[0] - b.BinRange.match(/\d+$/g)[0] )

console.log(input)
```